# How to mask a UIImage so that white becomes transparent on iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have a UIImage (generated by a user drawing) that has a white background. I'd like to make the white portions of this image transparent. I'd also like to save this to a PNG file.

I've looked around on forums but can't figure out how to mask the image correctly. Has anyone tried this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this...

```
CGImageRef myMaskedImage = [myImage CGImage];
const float whiteMask[6] = { 255,255,255, 255,255,255 };
CGImageRef myColorMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image, whiteMask);

CGDataProviderRef provider;
CGImageRef myPngImage = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 72], kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 72], kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth, nil];
CGImageDestinationRef destRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL ((CFURLRef)outPath, (CFStringRef)@"image.png" , 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destRef, myPngImage, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destRef);
CGRelease(destRef);

CGImageRelease(myColorMaskedImage);
CGImageRelease(myPngImage);
```

from the rather long winded [Quartz2d Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1) and [this mailing list message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2007/May/msg00002.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageByMakingWhiteBackgroundTransparent() -> UIImage? {

        let image = UIImage(data: self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!)!
        let rawImageRef: CGImage = image.cgImage!

        let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

        let maskedImageRef = rawImageRef.copy(maskingColorComponents: colorMasking)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.translateBy(x: 0.0,y: image.size.height)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.draw(maskedImageRef!, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return result

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you convert to jpeg first and then load it as such again? Is there a reason for it? Just want to understand what's going on here. The solution as such is working!

Comment: sorry bro, dont have more details now, answer i wrote is 2 years back

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the starting UIImage completely transparent and then have another UIImageView behind it that is completely white.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to get at the raw data, look for white pixels, modify the alpha of those pixels and save to a new NSData object and then convert that to a PNG.

It's not difficult, but I wouldn't call it trivial.