# GPUImage masking transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-image, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage framework of Brad Larson in my app and I need to make a mask of mask.jpg and photo. So mask images are two colors images with black background and white geometric figure. So basically masking is working, the problem is that I can't make the transparency of mask. To make that I need to replace the black color of mask.png to lighter color (more gray to white). 
So I tried to use code from here 
[Want to change a particular color inside an image with another color - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171679/want-to-change-a-particular-color-inside-an-image-with-another-color-iphone) 
But it doesn't work, the alpha is set to 0 and I don't know why. I tried to debug and everything seems to be fine, but it returns an UIImage with transparent color instead of black color.
Is there a way to make it without coregraphics. Maybe coreimage?

Comment: The real solution is not to replace a color but to actually use an input video that has already been split into RGB and Alpha channels. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079559/763355