# Optimizing nested for loops in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uiimage

I got this method that counts white pixels in a `UIImage`, I need to go through all the pixels to increase the counter with each white pixel that I find. I´m trying to improve the performance of it but I don´t find a better approach. Any ideas?

```
func whitePixelCount() -> Int {
    let width = Int(image.size.width)
    let height = Int(image.size.height)
    var counter = 0
    for x in 0..<(width*scale) {
        for y in 0..<(height*scale) {
            // We multiply per 4 because of the 4 channels, RGBA, but later we just use the Alpha
            let pixelIndex = (width * y + x) * 4

            if pointer[pixelIndex + Component.alpha.rawValue] == 255 {
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return counter
}
```

- `Component.alpha.rawValue` is equal to `3`
- `scale` is `Int(image.scale)`
- `pointer` comes from:

  ```
  guard let cfdata = self.image.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data,
      let pointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(cfdata) else {
          return nil
  }
  ```

Comment: Provide some more details on the performance. How did you benchmark this? What optimization flags are you bench-marking under? What images are in your test suite?

Comment: But in principle, this can only get so fast while it's running on the CPU. If you want this code to be performant, you could try to lift it to the GPU, but to do that, you would need to provide *a lot* more information on what exactly you're trying to do by counting white pixels.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31661519/1271826 for example of how to render image to pixel buffer. This is adapted Apple’s [Technical Q&A 1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1509/_index.html), which is an old Objective-C example of dealing with pixel buffers. The code snippet is outdated, but the general principles still apply.

Comment: Or, when you say “white pixels” did you mean “opaque pixels of any color”?

Comment: What I want to do is to know the exact number of white pixels in a black&white image, for each image I receive, and I receive a lot of them continuosly. Right now with this code, the processor is working at 130-140%, and I want to reduce the use of the CPU.

Comment: Yeah, but it looks like you’re assuming four bytes per pixel (e.g. a RGBA style format). So looking at the alpha channel tells you whether the pixel has any alpha or not, not the color of the pixel. Hey, if it works for you, fine, do whatever you want. E.g. maybe you’re dealing with a mask, not an image. But it just looks strange to say “I’m looking for white pixels”, whereas your code appears to be looking at alpha channel. But it’s not relevant to the question at hand, so I’ll drop it.

Comment: By question on your speed question is (a) are you measuring just the `for` loop; and (b) are you doing this in an optimized/release build? I ask that because, in my tests, my iPhone is processing that `for` loop for 12 megapixel image in 12-16 msec. Sure you can cut that down to ⅓ to ¼ to the time, but the time savings is about 0.01 seconds, generally not worth the effort.

Comment: You're right Rob! sorry I forgot to add that yes, I'm dealing with a mask :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Make sure you’re using an optimized/release build, not an unoptimized debug build. On my device, a debug build takes about 4 seconds to process a 12 megapixel image, whereas the release build takes 0.3 seconds.
2. When you have a `for` loop, you can parallelize it to leverage all of the cores on the CPU. By doing this with the striding algorithm, the `for` loop was almost 4 times faster.

   That sounds great, but unfortunately, the problem is that of the 0.3 seconds to process the image, most of that was the preparation of the image buffer. (Now, in your example, you’re not rerendering it into a predefined pixel buffer, which is a little dangerous IMHO, so maybe you don’t have this overhead. But, regardless, the difference of 10+ msec is not generally observable unless you’re processing hundreds of images.) The actual `for` loop was only accounting for 16 msec of the elapsed time. So while cutting that down to 4 msec is almost 4 times faster, but from a user perspective, it is immaterial.

Anyway, feel free to see the parallel algorithm with striding below, in my original answer.

---

One very simple approach to improving `for` loop performance is to use `concurrentPerform` to parallelize the routine:

For example, here is a non-parallelized routine:

```
var total = 0

for x in 0..<maxX {
    for y in 0..<maxY {
        if ... {
            total += 1
        }
    }
}

print(total)
```

You can parallelize it by

- Flipping the `x` and `y` loops, because we want the outer loop to be a row in the image. The idea is to ensure that not only should each thread be working with contiguous memory blocks, but we want to minimize the amount of overlapping to avoid “cache sloshing”. Thus consider:

  ```
  for y in 0..<maxY {
      for x in 0..<maxX {
          if ... {
              total += 1
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  We’re not actually going to use the above, but we’ll use it as a model in the next step;
- replacing the outer `for` loop (now the `y` coordinate) with `concurrentPerform`:

  ```
  var total = 0

  let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "...")

  DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: maxY) { y in
      var subTotal = 0
      for x in 0..<maxX {
          if ... {
              subTotal += 1
          }
      }
      syncQueue.sync {
          total += subTotal
      }
  }

  print(total)
  ```

So, the idea is:

- replace outer `for` loop with `concurrentPerform`;
- rather than trying update `total` for every iteration of `x`, have a `subTotal` variable for each thread and only update `total` at the end (minimizing contention from multiple threads for this shared resource); and
- use some synchronization mechanism (I’ve used a serial queue here, but any synchronization mechanism will work) to update `total` to ensure thread-safety.

I was trying to keep the example as simple as possible, but there are even other optimizations one can do:

- Different synchronization techniques offer different performance. E.g. you can use `NSLock` (which conventional wisdom says is slower, but my recent benchmarks suggest that the performance can be better than GCD in many scenarios) by defining a `sync` method in a protocol extension (to give a nice, safe way of using locks) like so:

  ```
  // Adapted from Apple’s `withCriticalSection` code sample

  extension NSLocking {
      func sync<T>(_ closure: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
          lock()
          defer { unlock() }
          return try closure()
      }
  }
  ```

  Then you can do something like:

  ```
  let lock = NSLock()

  DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: maxY) { y in
      var subTotal = 0
      for x in 0..<maxX {
          if ... {
              subTotal += 1
          }
      }
      lock.sync {
          total += subTotal
      }
  }

  print(total)
  ```

  Feel free to try whatever synchronization mechanisms you want. But the idea is that if you’re going to access `total` from multiple threads, make sure to do so in a thread-safe manner. Temporarily turn on the “Thread Sanitizer” if you want to check your thread-safety.
- If there’s not enough work on each thread (e.g. `maxX` isn’t very large or, as in this case, the algorithm is so fast), the overhead of the parallelized routine can start to offset the benefits of getting multiple cores involved in the calculation. So you can “stride” through multiple rows of `y` in each iteration. For example:

  ```
  let lock = NSLock()

  let stride = maxY / 20
  let iterations = Int((Double(height) / Double(stride)).rounded(.up))

  DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { i in
      var subTotal = 0
      let range = i * stride ..< min(maxY, (i + 1) * stride)
      for y in range {
          for x in 0 ..< maxX {
              if ... {
                  subTotal += 1
              }
          }
      }

      lock.sync { count += subTotal }
  }
  ```

Comment: You can see my code here: https://github.com/robertmryan/CountWhitePixels

Comment: Wow looks super good! thx you very much, I will try it this evening :) and yes, I'm analyzing 60 images per second, so, any ms I can save, will be good for the performance. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

In general big(o) performance can be increased by replaceing your for loops with a while loop thats says while x < array.count && y < array2.count { insert code to do here }

another approach is spliting your image into seperate components and sending them to different threads and recombining the resulting arrays. Youll want to use gcd * workitems async to do this.