# how to change the RGB value in UIImage at the position (x,y)? swift code

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to kown how to change the RGB value in UIImage at the position (x,y)?  ? does there a way to implement it?  i want implement it with swift code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried searching? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661023/change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-uiimage ?