# Swift self image creation and change

Tags: ios, swift, image, self

In Swift I have an image: (but {I think} the problem is how the 'self' is implemented)
(in my viewDidLoad)

```
let colorSpace       = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bytesPerPixel    = 4
let bitsPerComponent = 8
let bytesPerRow      = bytesPerPixel * self.cols // width
let bitmapInfo       = RGBA32.bitmapInfo
let minimapContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: self.cols, height: self.rows, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
let buffer = minimapContext!.data
self.pixelBuffer = buffer!.bindMemory(to: RGBA32.self, capacity: self.cols * self.rows) // was let

var pixelIndex = 1
```

Then I loop over an array of like:

```
self.pixelBuffer[pixelIndex] = .blue
```

This all works fine without the 'self'.

I want to change some of the pixels, so I added the 'self' and defined it at the top of the ViewController class

Now change the pixels like:

```
self.pixelBuffer[newPixelIndex] = .lightblue
```

But I get a variety of errors:
Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to type 'RGBA32'

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'lightblue'

Value of type 'RGBA32?' has no subscripts

Don't know if this helps but the pixelBuffer is defined ike:

```
var pixelBuffer: RGBA32? = nil
```

and here is RGBA32:

```
struct RGBA32: Equatable {
private var color: UInt32

init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
    color = (UInt32(red) << 24) | (UInt32(green) << 16) | (UInt32(blue) << 8) | (UInt32(alpha) << 0)
}

static let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue

static func ==(lhs: RGBA32, rhs: RGBA32) -> Bool {
    return lhs.color == rhs.color
}

static let black = RGBA32(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
static let red   = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
static let green = RGBA32(red: 24, green: 183, blue: 3, alpha: 255)
static let darkgreen = RGBA32(red: 70, green: 105, blue: 35, alpha: 255)
static let blue  = RGBA32(red: 0, green: 127, blue: 255, alpha: 255)
static let lightblue = RGBA32(red: 33, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 255)
static let brown = RGBA32(red: 127, green: 63, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
```

}

THANKS!!

Comment: What is an RGBA32?

Comment: Sorry, Added RGBA32 above

Comment: and it's based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661023/change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-uiimage

Comment: Thanks Matt!!
self.pixelBuffer?[pixelIndex] = RGBA32.lightblue
This got rid of a lot of errors. Error: "Value of type 'RGBA32' has no subscripts" remains and "Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>' to type 'RGBA32'" remains. I guess I need to get your book! :)

Comment: OK see my revised answer, sorry, I was misled by your code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you have declared `self.pixelBuffer` to be an Optional RGBA32. But that is not what `pixelBuffer` was before. It was a `UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>`. Here is the declaration you need:

```
var pixelBuffer : UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>!
```

All your issues will then go away, I think. Your

```
self.pixelBuffer[newPixelIndex] = .lightblue
```

then compiles for me.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! This is what I like so much about SO!
So can I remove the ? and RGBA32, like: self.pixelBuffer[pixelIndex] = .blue
or is it just better to leave them like: self.pixelBuffer?[pixelIndex] = RGBA32.blue  ?

Comment: Depends whether you use `!` like I did or `?` like you did.

Comment: When it runs I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10ce091e0) .  on the line: self.pixelBuffer[pixelIndex] = .green

Comment: Sorry, the question was about compiling, I thought. What happens when you run is another matter.