# How to replace the color of a pixel in an image?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, cgimage

I have a function that can return the color of a pixel by points

```
extension CGImage {
func colors(at: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue

    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo),
        let ptr = context.data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
            return .black
    }

    context.draw(self, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    let i = bytesPerRow * Int(at.y) + bytesPerPixel * Int(at.x)
    
    let a = CGFloat(ptr[i + 3]) / 255.0
    let r = (CGFloat(ptr[i]) / a) / 255.0
    let g = (CGFloat(ptr[i + 1]) / a) / 255.0
    let b = (CGFloat(ptr[i + 2]) / a) / 255.0
    
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

I would like to write a function that could replace the color of a pixel by Point
Can you please advise where to start?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First step should always be searching. Head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift replace color at point in uiimage` -- lots of results, and you'll almost certainly find your answer already out there.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, I looked but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, you need to be a little more descriptive than *"I looked but didn't find what I was looking for"* ... the code in this answer (first match when searching): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661023/change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-uiimage works well for me when replacing all pixels of a specific color. What are you trying to do? Do you want to set one pixel to a specific color? If so, you can easily modify that code. Or, you could use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`. But you need to show that you've tried something, and explain what *"didn't work for you"*

Comment: @DonMag Yes, you need to change the color in the image by points, it will always be one point, for example CGPoint (x: 0, y: 0)
before that, I wrote in Kotlin and it was made easier there, everything was done through the Bitmap in which there was a setColor method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what all you want to do, this may or may not be the appropriate  approach.

However, without additional information...

This func will set the pixel at `atPoint` to on `onImage` to `color`:

```
func setColor(color: UIColor, onImage: UIImage, atPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let rndr = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: onImage.size)
    let newImg = rndr.image { ctx in
        onImage.draw(at: .zero)
        let r = CGRect(origin: atPoint, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        ctx.cgContext.addRect(r)
        ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
    }
    return newImg
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "pixelTest") else { return }

    let modifiedImage = setColor(color: .red, onImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5))
```