# Capturing image of 3d object in Open GLES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I am new in Open GLES.
I want to capture the image of only 3d object, i don't want background view along with that image.
when i am trying to capture the image of 3d object, it is coming with glview(eaglLayer)  background but i don't want it.

Please help me regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could [capture the glview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html) and then [mask the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage) if it is a single color.

Answer (score 0):

```
(UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{
    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point, 
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

    // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }
    else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}
```