# I want to exchange a particular color inside an image with another color.  Is there any possible way?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, cocos2d-iphone, uicolor

I have one image with multiple colors.

I want to change a specific color with the alternate color that i have pre-decided.

Is there any algorithms to modify the image and save it?

Help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this something that needs to be done in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the selected answer to this question:

[How to make one color transparent on a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage)

It also shows turning red pixels green, which applies to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Definatly yes.

Look here
[Bitmap Images and Image Masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101)

Look in that page for: "Masking with color"