# Replace green color by transparent on a UIIMage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics

I draw green line on my UIImage with this : CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1);

It works well

But after i  want to replace my green strokes by transparent

I use this function :

```
    - (UIImage*) replaceColor:(UIColor*)color inImage:(UIImage*)image withTolerance:(float)tolerance {
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
NSUInteger bitmapByteCount = bytesPerRow * height;

unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(bitmapByteCount, sizeof(unsigned char));

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

CGColorRef cgColor = [color CGColor];
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(cgColor);
float r = components[0];
float g = components[1];
float b = components[2];
//float a = components[3]; // not needed

r = r * 255.0;
g = g * 255.0;
b = b * 255.0;

const float redRange[2] = {
    MAX(r - (tolerance / 2.0), 0.0),
    MIN(r + (tolerance / 2.0), 255.0)
};

const float greenRange[2] = {
    MAX(g - (tolerance / 2.0), 0.0),
    MIN(g + (tolerance / 2.0), 255.0)
};

const float blueRange[2] = {
    MAX(b - (tolerance / 2.0), 0.0),
    MIN(b + (tolerance / 2.0), 255.0)
};

int byteIndex = 0;

while (byteIndex < bitmapByteCount) {
    unsigned char red   = rawData[byteIndex];
    unsigned char green = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
    unsigned char blue  = rawData[byteIndex + 2];

    if (((red >= redRange[0]) && (red <= redRange[1])) &&
        ((green >= greenRange[0]) && (green <= greenRange[1])) &&
        ((blue >= blueRange[0]) && (blue <= blueRange[1]))) {
        // make the pixel transparent
        //
        rawData[byteIndex] = 0;
        rawData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
        rawData[byteIndex + 2] = 0;
        rawData[byteIndex + 3] = 0;
    }

    byteIndex += 4;
}

UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];

CGContextRelease(context);
free(rawData);

return result;
    }
```

That i found on [How to make one color transparent on a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage)

I don't know why but all green pixels who are located at the border of the stroke are still in the UIImage

Any idea ?

Here is the result picture (the path of the stroke is in the middle, you can see some green pixels around)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [UIColor ClearColor] Insted ?

Comment: Use [UIColor ClearColor] instead of green when i draw the line ? i know but i don't want to do it, as when the user draw, i want the stroke  appears in green.

Comment: When i draw i use this option : CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound); i was thinking, maybee i got this problem because pixels at the border of the stroke have their color automatically mitigate ? if i use tolerance = 100 in my method, the problem is solved, but of course i can't do it as a lot of others pixels which are not from my stroke are removed as well

Comment: i just discovered that this issue is not related to the replace color function, but with the fact that when i stroke my line, some pixels have shadow/blur effect. i will close this question and open another one