# Change a PNG image's background from white to transparent

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a PNG image file and I'm using a UIImageView to show the image in a view. I want to change the **white color** to **transparent** in my image.

**Note: my parent view color can be different colours. (not just white)**

Here is my code:

```
UIImageView* oriImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:originalFrame];
UIImage* oriImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tap.png"];
oriImageView.layer.opacity = 0.5f;
oriImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
oriImageView.opaque = NO;
oriImageView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
oriImageView.image = oriImage;
[self.view addSubview:oriImageView];
```

I have tried different options in SO as following with no luck.

```
oriImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
oriImageView.opaque = NO;
oriImageView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]

My iOS simulator screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You will need to change the image, remove the white background and make it transparent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I only have png image, can I change it to transparent background? I don't have the vector file.

Comment: Yes you can use a image editing program to do that, but it might not be that easy.

Comment: this is not fully trasperenat image as @rckoenes said you need to remove the white color from your image

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage) might be the last thing you want to try.

Answer (score 5):

this code will work when your background color is white, change color value according to your need

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageByMakingWhiteBackgroundTransparent() -> UIImage? {

        let image = UIImage(data: self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!)!
        let rawImageRef: CGImage = image.cgImage!

        let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

        let maskedImageRef = rawImageRef.copy(maskingColorComponents: colorMasking)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.translateBy(x: 0.0,y: image.size.height)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.draw(maskedImageRef!, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return result

    }

}
```

Comment: Swift 5, iOS 14 works perfectly still! Thanks